# Using querySelectAll, can't figure out how to insert a white space after periods and quotation marks

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

So, I recently started digging into using dom parsing for editing html code after people suggested I should use that instead of trying to use the replace() method a lot. Everything is going fine so far, however, today I stumbled upon a problem I cannot figure out. My goal is to insert a white space after a period or quotation mark if it is missing. For example, I want to make this "This is a test.Really!" into this "This is a test. Really!" or this "This is a 'blah'test" into this "This is a 'blah' test". I tried different things but just can't seem to get it to work. So maybe you can help me out.

Right now I have this:

```js
doc.querySelectorAll('*:not(a):not(img)').forEach(element => {
  const space = element.textContent;
  const dspace = space.replace(/(\S)([.,:;!?])(\S|$)|(\w)(["'])(\S|$)/g, "$1$2 $3");
  element.textContent = dspace;
});
```

I excluded the anchor and image elements because within these there shouldn't be any white spaces because they wouldn't work anymore.

I tried different regex using stuff like `"[^\s]" and "?!\s"`. I also have other code but I disabled that code (using `/* */`) temporarily to check if that code messes it up but it's still not working. I really have no clue what's going on with this.

Comment: Please add some HTML to the demo above so we can see the problem. FYI, it's probably not wise to iterate over every element in the page that isn't an image or anchor. That's going to be slowwwww. See if you can narrow the scope a bit.

Comment: Oops, I got confused the "query" in the "querySelect", sorry for the confusion!
I don't think I cluttered my post with the AI as I only mentioned that I tried using it to check if my code should work. But I won't use that name here again.
I'm not sure how I can best implement the HTML. The purpose of the whole code is that a user can input a html code into a text area and with a button press some things change (like adding white spaces). I don't know which part of the HTML i should add to my post.
Also, I changed the code to only look in p, il and div elements, thanks for the tip ^^